# Can not control-drag from WebView to ViewController.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I want to create a `WebView` in View Controller.

I try to *control-drag from WebView to `ViewController.h`*, but it is not showing me the blue connector.

Is there something I am missing?

Please help. Thank you.

P.S. 
I search keyword "web view connect" and "web view" on Apple Documentation, it is showing me `WebKit` something like that. What is the keyword should I type?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIn2h.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBHu9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following things:

1)Make sure that the .h file that you are control + dragging onto is the header file for your view controller. You can check this by checking the identity tab for your view controller in the utilities pane and making sure that the class name for the controller matches the header file name that you are control + dragging to.

2)Make sure that you are control + dragging in between the @interface and the @end like such:

```
@interface ViewController:UIViewController

// Control + Drag into this area

@end
```

Comment: 1) I don't know what is this... Could you say it clearly, please!!   (2) Yes, I put the blue connector in that.

Comment: Basically, what I am saying is to check that the class name for your view controller matches the name of the .h file you are dragging onto. For example, if you are working on a UIViewController with class name FirstViewController , make sure you are dragging onto FirstViewController.h and not some other header file.

Comment: I try it for 2 hours, still not. I don't understand what should I do. I don't know I am working on UIViewController or not, how do I check this?   Do I gave you more information?   I must solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared instance variable like `IBOutlet _webView;` in your `ViewController.h` file, if not, Xcode can't show blue connector.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is declared, maybe I know that thing just don't know the name...  This is photo. http://imgur.com/tzCAaHS

Comment: You can declare the instance variable with any valid name as you like. It just a reference to the `WebView` in nib file. When you connect the `WebView` to the instance, you can reference the instance as you reference the `WebView` in nib file.

Comment: I am new for Xcode and computer language...Sorry, I don't understand what is declare the instance variable or reference to the WebView in nib  ...,Could you say it clearly please!!@youmingtaiz